# Unable to find PORT name in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: usb, ubuntu-12.04, serial-port, com-port

I am writing a code for serial programming in  ubuntu 12.04. I have connected a usb to serial converter with my usb port. Now I want to know On which port I have connected my usb ( for example COM12 COM13 etc).I have tried command

```
lsusb
```

It is showing my device connected but not in ways I want. Actually my output of this command is like this

```
tabish@tabish-Vostro-1450:/dev$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 1004:631f LG Electronics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:21d7 Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0c45:643e Microdia 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 067b:2303 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303 Serial Port
```

So, I can see my device in the last line but not in the way I want. So please tell the command to check PORT name in windows style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running `dmesg` after plugging in the USB-to-serial device. You should see messages at the bottom of the log referring to the device. It will most likely be called `/dev/ttyUSB0` or something similar.

Comment: I have already tried this, I got my usb name as /dev/ttyUSB0 , but I want my name as COM12 or something like this ( Just as windows)

Comment: Linux doesn't have COM* names for serial ports. You need to use `/dev/ttyUSB0`.